# ValueError: too many values to unpack with too many tuples

Tags: python

I get an error while sorting about 470000 tuples. 
I read data from csv file into list of tuples

```
fp = open(filename, 'Ur')
for line in fp:
  listOfCitiesTuples.append(tuple(line.strip().split(',')))
fp.close()
```

Tuples are some cities names associated with a number.

```
[('Chiredzi', '4117'), ('Gaths', '4117'), ('Masvingo', '4117'), ('Chivhu', '4120'), ('Gweru', '4120'), ('Kwekwe', '4120'), ('Mvuma', '4120'), ('Redcliffe', '4120'), ('Shurugwi', '4120'), ('Zvishavane', '4120')]
```

I collect all the names associated to same number together in a list and map it to that number and form a dict of all those items, something like this

```
{'1': ['Bombuflat', 'Garacharma', 'Port Blair', 'Rangat'], '113': ['Hydra', 'Kouba'], '294': ['Vienna', 'Wien'], '1327': ['Lambarene', 'Ndjole']}
```

Using following method to achieve it

```
for k, v in listOfCitiesTuples:  dictOfCitiesTuples.setdefault(v, []).append(k)
```

This works fine for a smaller number of tuples( I have tested 20,000 so far), but doesn't seem to be working on larger number like 470000.

Could large number of tuples be a problem or could it be due to corrupted file? If it is due to some corrupted data in a file, is there something I can do to find out what corrupted data it is like try, exception ?

I get this error

```
File "/../view.py", line 186, in getCities
    for k, v in listOfCitiesTuples:  dictOfCitiesTuples.setdefault(v, []).append(k)
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: Import this tuple in a pandas dataframe and check for corrupted data in the file.

Comment: What's the full error? It's more likely you have 1 or 3 values which you are unpacking into two. Maybe a city has a comma in its name so you are getting 3 values.

Comment: @jas that's not the full error. What line of code is being executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your title `ValueError: too many values to unpack` you have some data in a different format than you are expecting.

Specifically, some lines have more than one comma which will make a tuple with more than 2 values, which then causes the error when you try to unpack them.

While you are iterating over the file, you can check if the tuple is the correct length. If you find bad data, you can make a note of it and fix it, or ignore it. Depends on your needs.

```
with open(filename, 'Ur') as infile:
    for line_num, line in enumerate(infile):
      vals = tuple(line.strip().split(','))
      if len(vals) == 2:
          listOfCitiesTuples.append(vals)
      else:
          bad_data.append((line_num, line))
```

Comment: Problem was one  line had two commas i.e Putignano,,1872. Thanks for the trick to find the line

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your code and taking a guess, what might be happening is the last line of the file could be an extra line with nothing in it.  So `line.strip().split(',')` returns a list of size `1`, which becomes a tuple of size `1` which blows up in your for-loop.  Add the following guard:

```
fp = open(filename, 'Ur')
for line in fp:
  if len(line.strip()) > 0:
    listOfCitiesTuples.append(tuple(line.strip().split(',')))
fp.close()
```

Comment: You could ask a question instead of having to guess. It's up to OP to clarify their question.

Comment: @pgreen2 problem was due to corrupted data. one line was causing the issue